# Error in using rand function

Tags: c, random

I tried using the rand() function with min = 4 and max = 10:

```
s = rand() % 10 + 4;
```

and some of the results were above 10.How is this possible?

Comment: You add 4. Don't you want `rand()%6+4`?

Comment: I think rand() % 6 + 4 has the limits [4,9].How about rand() % 7 + 4 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you look for is `rand() % 7 + 4` which will give you results from range [4, 10]. More general, for given `min` and `max` to obtain random value from [min, max] you go for `rand() % (max - min + 1) + min`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply.I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

`s = rand() % 7 + 4;` is what you need, if you want `4 <= s <= 10`.

This is because `4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10` are 7 numbers. `rand() % 7` gives you a number from 0 to 6. Add 4 to it and you'll get the desired random number.